# Why aren't pending suggested edits automatically approved when you get 2000 rep?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

This happened to me today:

1. At the start of the day, I had 1981 reputation (or so).
2. I suggested an edit to a post.
3. I gained 20 reputation, thereby getting 2001 reputation and gaining the privilege to bypass the suggested edits queue.

However, the edit I suggested in (2), wasn't approved yet. Why not?

Comment: The edits are (usually) reviewed so fast that I don't know if this would be worth the effort.

Comment: If you take a downvote and your reputation goes back to 1999, should that edit be unapproved and put back in the suggested edits queue?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes, and all other edits you've made. Eh, no. Good point, this shows how inflexible editing would be when it was like I'd expect it to be.

Comment: And, from a design point of view: you did suggest that edit when you might not have known enough about the system/community. That suggestion might still be not as good as any edit you made after you passed the limit. Likewise: what if your very first suggested edit was also still in the queue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually can (partially)approve it yourself. At 2000 reputation, you can approve edits inline (there will be an `edit(1)` link on the post).

If this is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

Suggested edits are dealt with pretty quickly on most sites, so I don't think that this should be a major problem.

If this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)-report:

At 2k rep, you stop making suggested edits and are able to edit directly. The edit you just made was a suggested edit -- it won't be converted, since the 2k privilege is not about that.

Comment: Nice for the statistics and future questions here: suggested by Camil, approved by Camil. :-)

Comment: No [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request], I thought it would be intentionally, so just [tag:support]. Clear explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Suggested edits are suggested edits. They need to go through review. Your gaining 2k rep in the mean time doesn't change anything, that's still an edit suggestion you made.

When you reach 2k rep, you're not making suggested edits anymore, you're making plain edits that don't go through the queue at all. (Except for tag wiki/excerpt edits, until you reach 20k rep.)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, that is such a corner case (that moreover "heals itself" as explained in comments/answers) that it doesn't make sense to complicate the code for it.